# Jquery won't recognize non table cells as descendants in table rows?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

Working on a tooltip for a table row, I put a span in a table row with a class of "tip" and then tried to select that through find('.tip') but this wouldn't work.

```
$(".tip_trigger").hover(function(){
tip = $(this).find('.tip');
tip.show();
```

When I put the .tip class on a td it worked fine showing the tooltip.

Comment: what does your `HTML` look like?

Answer (score 6):

If you use invalid elements/structure, you'll get unpredictable results :)

A `<span>` cannot be  a child of a `<tr>`, you should lay it out a different way, for example putting that `<span>` inside a `<td>` in the row.

Comment: thanks @nick.  totally clear. i was able to fix by modifying the layout of the markup. anyone know a good reference of, like, a markup tree that shows relationships between tags/selectors in order of ascension?